# pass_proxy not listening to containers using nginx in docker

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm preparing a docker based dev environment for node and nginx but for some reason the nginx `pass_proxy` is not pointing to the container using their service name.

Here are the configuration files:

**default.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://web;
    }
}
```

**nginx Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.17-alpine
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  web:
    build: ../backend
    container_name: backend
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ../backend:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 6060:3000
  server:
    build: .
    restart: always
    container_name: nginx_server
    volumes:
      - ./log-nginx:/var/log/nginx/
    depends_on:
      - web
    ports:
      - 6000:80
```

I have exposed the `web` as well and it works when i visit `localhost:6060` but if i go to the nginx endpoint by going to this address `localhost:6000/api` it shows an error page in the browser:

> This site can’t be reached

Note that in the `default.conf` file i have tried using different variations for the `pass_proxy`container name, for example:

- `proxy_pass http://web;`
- `proxy_pass http://web:3000;`
- `proxy_pass web:3000;`
- `proxy_pass web;`

but it seems like non of them are working for nginx to shine. The logs file of nginx are also empty! what I might be missing here?
One more thing, I am using the alpine based official images.

Comment: It's supposed to be `proxy_pass http://web:6060` because that is the endpoint of your web app which nginx will proxy pass the requests into

Comment: @ToanQuocHo Still not working!

Comment: Oh sorry, it's web:3000. Just take a more careful look at the docker-compose file. Have you try to connect to the web container via nginx container? You can access to nginx container then use curl to test that. And maybe something might be wrong with your nginx config so you could take a look at the nginx error logs too